# JComponents are not not visible

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In my program I can't see the components or the slider I want to create (I tested other JComponents)
Code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
frame.setVisible(true);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
JSlider slider = new JSlider();
slider.setBounds(0, 0, slider.getHeight(), slider.getWidth());
panel.add(slider);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

frame.add() also doesn't work.
Other components also aren't working.

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout. 2) Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Sliders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) for a working example that will demonstrate how to use a JSlider and how to use a layout manager..

Comment: 1) I want to have the slider on a specific coordinate. 2) Other components like JLabel also don't work.

Comment: 1) There is no need to have a component at a specific location.  Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Learn how to use layout manager and the slider will be displayed in the position you want. If you specify the requirement, then we can assist on suggestion the best layout manager to use. 2) Of course. All Swing components are the same. They are designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the ..

Comment: .. *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 4) As an aside, none of the people (worth listening to) will help to 'fix' a `null` layout GUI, given they know the fix is to ***use* layouts.** 5) `frame.setVisible(true);` should be last, and called immediately after `frame.pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

This minimal, runnable example seems to work fine for me.

1. Always start your Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that your Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. The methods to create a JFrame have to be called in a specific order.  The example uses the order that I use for almost all of my Swing applications.
3. Swing is designed to be used with [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  A `FlowLayout` is the default layout manager.

Here's the minimal, runnable example.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SliderTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SliderTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Slider Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        panel.add(slider);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't see your components because they have size 0.

This line:

```
slider.setBounds(0, 0, slider.getHeight(), slider.getWidth());
```

is wrong, because slider's size is already 0, which you set it to.

To fix it, replace it with something more meaningful, such as:

```
slider.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 200);
```

Comment: (1-) *replace it with something more meaningful* - how is that more meaningful? The reason you don't do this is because any number you hard code is just a random number. That is why you learn to code Swing properly and use a layout manager.

Comment: Until you understand *why* that is such poor advice, please refrain from trying to help with problems related to cross-platform GUI development.

Comment: @camickr I am aware what you are talking about, however the question wasn't how to correctly create cross platform gui, but why a component is not visible, which I believe I have answered. And yes, any number >0, even hard coded, is in this context more meaningful that "basically hardcoded" 0s. Yes, using layout is better.

Comment: *the question wasn't how to correctly create cross platform gui,* - but that is how we answer questions so the OP can learn to effectively use Swing and prevent problems in the future. Many questions are asked because of lack of knowledge and the OP thinks it is the only solution. It is not and there is certainly no valid reason given in the question that the OP should use a null layout.

Comment: That's fine if you think that, you can add your improved answer that uses layouts, I'm not making any assumptions about OP's knowledge.